# Триггерная функция, которая удаляет роль

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin4

Код триггерной функции:

`begin
  prepare myfun(text) as 
   drop role $1;
  execute myfun(old.employee_login);
 end;`

При попытке сохранения выдает ошибку : ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "drop"). В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий код:

```
begin
 execute 'DROP ROLE '|| old.employee_login;
 return null;
end;
```